# Why can not I enter texts continually when using TexInput component with a props

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to make a TextInput component as a child with a function which is from the parent component.

but then, I can't enter texts as usual(I have to set the cursor every after I enter 1 text  )

would you mind tell me how to resolve this problem?

thank you in advance.

---

the parent component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import TestListInputItem from "../components/TestListInputItem";

export default function HomeScreen() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");

  const setInputName = (text) => {
    setName(text);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TestListInputItem name={name} setInputName={setInputName} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

the child component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TextInput,
} from "react-native";

export default function TestListInputItem(props) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);

  function handleMakeNew() {
    setCount((v) => v + 1);
  }

  function RenderList() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.list}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.InputName}
          value={String(props.name)}
          onChangeText={(text) => {
            props.setInputName(text);
          }}
        ></TextInput>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            handleMakeNew();
          }}
          style={styles.buttonAdd}
        >
          <Text>Add</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }

  return [...Array(count).keys()].map((i) => <RenderList key={i} />); 
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  list: {
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: "#ddd",
    padding: 10,
  },
  InputName: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    height: 40,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
  },
  buttonAdd: {
    backgroundColor: "orange",
    width: 80,
    height: 40,
    margin: 3,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    alignSelf: "center",
  },
});
```

---

Node: 12.18.3

React-Native: 4.10.1

Expo: 3.22.3

Comment: its prolly because you are destructuring an array in the render which creates a new array every time so you are unmounting the component aka reseting the state

Comment: @Eric Hasselbring,I see, but I have to keep this code `return [...Array(count).keys()].map((i) => <RenderList key={i} />); `because of a specification of this project

Comment: what is the specification that would require that, is it just to be able to edit the previous ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I commented, the issues is that your function is creating a new array on every render resetting your state, here's a quick modification that should set you in the right direction

```
  export default function AddItem(props) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.list}>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.InputName}
        value={props.value}
        onChangeText={(text) => {
          props.setValue(text);
        }}
      ></TextInput>
    </View>
  );
}

export default function TestListInputItem(props) {
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  function handleMakeNew() {
    setList((v) => [...v, value]);
  }

  return (
    <View>
      {
        list.map((item, i) => <View key={i}><Text>{item}</Text></View>)
      }
      <AddItem
        value={value}
        setValue={setValue}
      />
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          handleMakeNew();
        }}
        style={styles.buttonAdd}
      >
        <Text>Add</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: Although I tried that code, I still have to set the cursor every after I enter 1 text...

Comment: ok ill edit the code quick, the other thing is to re-organize your prop structure, you wouldn't want to nest a component inside another components render cycle in this particular instance

Comment: ok, the snippet should work but you will have to set up the new file for the input, and remove the `HomeScreen` state logic as its not needed and generally a place where you wouldn't keep such state

Comment: sorry made a couple of mistakes, `list.map((item, i)` and `{item}` needs braces for value otherwise string

Comment: Thank you so much your help, the method  to nest a component or not  doesn't matter, as long as if I could add or delete this component`<RenderList key={i} />`and use its value in the parent component as a state.

Comment: I'm sorry for asking many times, how should I replace these parts`list.map((item, i)` and `{item}`?

Comment: now I enter texts continually, and how can I add a whole this component `  <View>
      {list.map((item, i) => (
        <View key={i}>
          <Text>{item}</Text>
        </View>
      ))}
      <AddItem value={value} setValue={setValue} />
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          handleMakeNew();
        }}
        style={styles.buttonAdd}
      >
        <Text>Add</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>`when I press Add button?

Comment: thank you I will try to modify that code to what I want

Answer (score 0):

This is known as cursor jumping. To avoid this, in your Input component, maintain a local state and use that state value as input value. when onChange is fired, update the local state value first and then send it to the parent component

Comment: although I tried some way to solve it, I could not... would you mind tell me an example code to solve the cursor jumping in case of my code?

Comment: can you please provide any link where I can see and play with the code?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a beginner to react-native so now I have no idea how can I provide you the way you could play the code...

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the child component,

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TextInput,
} from "react-native";

export default function TestListInputItem(props) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

  function handleMakeNew() {
    setCount((v) => v + 1);
  }

  const handleInput =(text) =>{
     setInputValue(text)
      props.setInputName(text)
   }

  function RenderList() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.list}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.InputName}
          value={inputValue}
          onChangeText={(text) => {
            handleInput(text);
          }}
        ></TextInput>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            handleMakeNew();
          }}
          style={styles.buttonAdd}
        >
          <Text>Add</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Although I tried that code, I still have to set the cursor every after I enter 1 text...

Comment: create a expo snack so that I can see the code. https://snack.expo.io/